# External Drive With Every Version of OS X/macOS

Tags: macos, hard-drive

Is it possible to install every version of OS X / macOS to a bootable thumb drive/external hard drive so you can boot off of it?

edit: so I'm ignoring PowerPC stuff because it is rather old now.  Also my main question wonders if the max number of partitions could be an issue.

Comment: You may run into an issue with the number of partitions on a hard drive that are actually bootable. I don't recall the exact limitations but something says more than four bootable partitions will either not work or be problematic. It's been a while since I had to do something like so I am unsure, you could always try and report back...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Newer os want GUID partition scheme. Others want apple partition map.

You can surely put all the images on one drive, just the bootable aspect is problematic.

Comment: Hmm so I need 2 drIves then?  Keep in mind only newer computers post 2007 I think support booting to USB so this eliminates the super old stuff

Comment: @William two should be safe. Do try booting from USB even if you see it’s not supported. We USB booted many Mac OS before they supported it  - test before you rule out one connection over the other.